# Javafx: Java applet in a Webview component

Tags: java, webview, applet, javafx-2

Is there a way to show a Java Applet in a JavaFX WebView component? Is it not a supported functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't display an applet in a WebView.
WebView does not support plugin technology such as applets.

Comment: thanks, but as far as you know is there any non-standard self-made component that can help me with this task?

Comment: No, there is no such component to do integrate Applet and WebView technology.

Answer (score 1):

Javafx Webview does not support applet, in fact, the netscape.JSObject in plugin.jar is deliberately crippled. You can, however, roll up your applet support code, you may be interested in webfx https://github.com/brunoborges/webfx, there are some applet support sample code

Answer (score 0):

You can use sun.applet.AppletViewer to open applet through webview. Go through the AppletViewer you can understand how you will do.

Here is the URL you found something - http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/applet/AppletViewer.java.html

I hope it will help you