# JavaFX WebView: Java not accessible

Tags: java, webview, applet, javafx, javafx-webengine

I am trying to load a webpage into my application. I can get the page to load, however, the website I'm trying to load requires Java to run and the WebView cannot seem to find it on my MacBook. See my stripped code below:

```
public class LoadPage extends Application {

    public static WebView loadPage() {
        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine eng = browser.getEngine();
        eng.load("http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp");
        return browser;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
            pane.setCenter(loadPage());
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("WebEditor");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Now my question is: Is there a workaround for this? Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that, the `WebView` currently doesn't support plugin technology ! Please see [Jewelsea's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea) answer over here !

[Javafx: Java applet in a Webview component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200188/javafx-java-applet-in-a-webview-component)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick response :) Then in what programming language would I be able to create a similar program? I know it is possible :)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha: can you help me with this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/22088217/2722799

Comment: @pietv8x Please go through http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/174751/pure-java-web-browser-is-it-practical